# Activity indicator in SdWebImage issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview, sdwebimage

I have a horizontal collection view and it has 20 cells with UIImageView
I just want to show the activity indicator till the image download completed. I am using the new SDWebImage library where we have methods as **sd_setImageWithURL**
Till now What i am doing is

```
__block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center = cell.photoOneImageView.center;
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

[cell.photoOneImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://scontent-sjc.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p480x480/11073324_10153728863852926_4010319763478440264_n.jpg?oh=590934059508b7da235a46fc39e08063&oe=55B61458"] 
placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"] 
completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error,  SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }];

[cell.photoOneImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

I am writing this code in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method
It shows sometimes multiple indicators on 1 cell and they are not removing also sometimes when we scroll the collection view horizontally.

I saw this https://github.com/rs/SDNetworkActivityIndicator but I am unable to use this. No luck with that. Has anyone implemented activity indicator in tebleview cell or collection view cell when the image completed the indicator vanish. Please help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are calling addSubview in cellForRow, rather make the activity indicator a part of your cell.

Comment: is there any other method...

Comment: You can make the activity indicator a part of your custom cell just like you aren't adding a photoOneImageView every time....

Comment: u mean to say i should add it as a placeholder..and keep it animating behind. How can i achieve it.. I am passing just a .jpg in setimagewithurl function.pls help

Comment: Its not a placeholder, it simply animates when its loading and stops animating when the completion block is called. Its everything you have been doing just don't keep adding a random indicator to a cell:)

Comment: can you provide some sample snippet... I am still unable to get you,,If I put a custom activity indicator that the placeholder will overlap it..I have to add on the imageview externally only

Comment: Kindly check my answer below and tell us if it worked for u. @RajanMaheshwari

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to use SDWebImage's default activity indicator available in the latest repo

**Updates: SWIFT 5 SDWebImage 5.x.x**

```
        cell.imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cache, urls) in
            if (error != nil) {
                // Failed to load image
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
            } else {
                // Successful in loading image
                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
```

swift 3 :

```
cell.imageView.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
cell.imageView.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cache, urls) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Failed to load image
                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
                } else {
                    // Successful in loading image
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that you are adding a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on a cell that might get dequed and reused later on before your block triggers.

To fix this, make the activity indicator a property of your cell:

```
@interface Cell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView activityIndicator;

@end
```

Then, your implementation should look like this:

```
@implementation Cell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self initialize];
}

- (void)initialize
{
    // This code is only called once
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.photoOneImageView.center;
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.photoOneImageView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
}

@end
```

Then:

```
[cell.photoOneImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://somesite.com/pic.jpg"] 
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"] 
                                 completed:
    ^(UIImage *image, NSError *error,  SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }];

[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage to fix the issue.

Very simple to load image with an activity indicator

```
[cell.photoOneImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://scontent-sjc.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p480x480/11073324_10153728863852926_4010319763478440264_n.jpg?oh=590934059508b7da235a46fc39e08063&oe=55B61458"] 
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]
    usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3 
For extension UIImageView+Download+Extension.swift:

```
import SDWebImage

extension UIImageView {
    func setImageWithIndicator(imageUrl: String, callback: ((_ image: UIImage) -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard !imageUrl.isEmpty else {
            return
    }

        if let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl), url.host != nil {
            self.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
            self.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            self.sd_setImage(with: url as URL!, completed: { (_, _, _, _) in
        })
     }
   }
}
```

using:

```
UIImageView.setImageWithIndicator(imageUrl: url)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a separate CollectionView cell, to get reused.

or just do this after creating collectionviewcell:

```
  for (__strong UIView *view in Cell.contentView.subviews) {
if([view isKindofClass: [UIActivityIndicatorView class]]])
{

        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;}
    }
```

Because you  are always creating new object of activityindicatorView